# mysql join 3 tables and display result with WHERE payment = PENDING

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables

```
abd_table
  product_name
  price
  quantity
  total_cost
  session_id
  date

order_detail_table
  order_id
  product_name
  price
  quantity
  total_cost
  session_id
  order_date

order_table
  order_id
  payment_status (PAID,PENDING)
  order_date
  session_id
```

I want to retreive rows

1) WHERE same PRODUCT DETAILS dont exists or match in abd_table and order_detail_table from same session

2) WHERE nw.payment_status = PENDING

If i remove WHERE CONDITION from below query then it dispaly all rows whether the payment_status is pending or not. 
if i insert WHERE CONDITION in the below query then it display nothing.

```
$qry="select 
a.cart_id,a.date,a.quantity,a.total_cost,a.user_name,a.product_name,a.session_id,a.price,o.order_id,nw.payment_status,nw.session_id
from abd_table AS a
LEFT JOIN order_detail_table as o on a.session_id=o.session_id
LEFT JOIN order_table as nw on o.session_id = nw.session_id
where nw.payment_status = 'PENDING'";
```

so how to retreive rows

1) WHERE same PRODUCT DETAILS dont exists or match in abd_table and order_detail_table from same session.

2) WHERE nw.payment_status = PENDING

vineet

Comment: Change WHERE to AND

Comment: @Strawberry if i change WHERE to AND, then it displays all rows including the PAID orders. I dont want to show PAID enteries

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but I think you need to add `or nw.payment_status is null` to your `where`-condition, because right now, you neglect the "same PRODUCT DETAILS dont exists"-part (assuming I understand that correctly).

Comment: @Solarflare do you want to replace WHERE with OR. i replaced WHERE with OR. but this time also it returns all rows including paid.

Comment: @vineet, no you have to add it, your where condition should be `where nw.payment_status = 'PENDING' or nw.payment_status is null`

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Solarflare thanks a lot. this mixture of where and or clauses worked great

Comment: @Solarflare how would i add another condition of a.date >='2016-08-12'

Comment: @Solarflare i mean how to show records which have particular date 2016-08-12 or greater than 2016-08-12

Comment: @vineet Your `where`-condition should be `where (nw.payment_status = 'PENDING' or nw.payment_status is null) and a.date >= '2016-08-12'`. But I think you should look at an sql tutorial to get a better understanding of how to write basic `select` querys (e.g. [and & or operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)). Your original question had a little non-trivial twist because of the `left join`, but adding another condition doesn't. (Please don't hesitate to ask again, that's really not what I mean, but I'm sure you don't want to ask here for every little adjustment to your query).

Comment: @Solarflare thanks for the solutions. This works great. I myself tried already what you have posted as solution but i was missing the ( ) brackets. therefore it was giving different results and i was not able to know why the results of other dates were also showing. But now i know that i was missing the ( ) brackets. thanks again for help.